# Jquery datatables doesn't split

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datatables

In an ASP.NET MVC project I have a datatable in a view that doesn't split in multiple pages.
I have the following code :

```js
table = $('#tableEtape3').dataTable({
  'aoColumnDefs': [
    { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [9/*, 10, 11*/] },
    { 'mRender': function (data, type, row) {
        if (row["IDAFFAIRE"]!= null) {
          return '<a href="/Affaire/Edit/' + row["IDAFFAIRE"].substr(7) + '" target="_blank">' + row["IDAFFAIRE"].substr(7) + '</a>';
        }
      },
      'aTargets': [0]
    },
    { 'mRender': function (data, type, row) {
        if (row["N_CHANT"] != null) {
          return '<a href="/SuiviChantier/Edit/' + row["N_CHANT"] + '" target="_blank">' + row["REF_DEVIS"] + '</a>';
        }
      },
      'aTargets': [1]
   }
   ...
  ],
  'bFilter': true,
  "oLanguage": {
      "oPaginate": {
          "sFirst": " Première page", // This is the link to the first page
          "sPrevious": "Page précédente", // This is the link to the previous page
          "sNext": "Page suivante", // This is the link to the next page
          "sLast": "Dernière page" // This is the link to the last page
      },
      "sInfo": "Elements _START_ à _END_ sur _TOTAL_",
      "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_  éléments par page",
      "sSearch": "Rechercher : ",
      "sEmptyTable": "Aucune donnée",
      "sInfoEmpty": "0 éléments",
  },
  'sPaginationType': 'bootstrap',
  'bServerSide': true,
  'sAjaxSource': '/FacturationFinMois/GetEtape3Table',
  'bProcessing': true,
  'bStateSave': true,
  'bAutoWidth': true,
  'fnServerParams': function (aoData) {
      aoData.push(
          { 'name': 'mois', 'value': $('#MoisSelected').val() },
          { 'name': 'corpo', 'value': $('#CorpoSelected').val() },
          { 'name': 'tech', 'value': $('#TechSelected').val() }
      );
  },
  'aoColumns': [
      { mDataProp: 'IDAFFAIRE', sTitle: 'Affaire', sType: 'numeric', sWidth: '' },
      { mDataProp: 'REF_DEVIS', sTitle: 'Devis', sType: 'numeric', sWidth: '' },
      ...
  ]
});
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm12 col-md-12">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-datatable table-bordered" id="tableEtape3" />
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in the following picture, the datatable is generated with the length menu, the page navigator at the end etc... But I have every rows of my table on the same page.

[Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym6bS.png)

Is there anyone who've run into the same issue ?

Comment: I get an error when running your code snippet:                                                           
         {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 34,
  "colno": 4
}

Comment: The ajax is binded to my ASP.NET application in the code snippet

Comment: When do you load the data into your table, before or after you call the .dataTable() function?

Comment: Data are load on draw event that happend on declaration of the datatable